# SOAP API: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

Tags: visualforce, soap-api, permissions, profile

I created a VF page to call SOAP API (version 57) for decribeLayout for a custom object with defined record type. It has payload

```
<se:Envelope xmlns:se="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<se:Header xmlns:sfns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
    <sfns:SessionHeader>
        <sessionId>SESSIONID_ABC_XYZ</sessionId>
    </sfns:SessionHeader>
    <sfns:CallOptions>
        <client>api_token</client>
    </sfns:CallOptions>
</se:Header>
<se:Body>
    <describeLayout xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"
        xmlns:ns1="sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
        <sObjectType>CustomObject__c</sObjectType>
        <layoutName xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nill="true" />
        <recordTypeIds>0122x000000V62QAAS</recordTypeIds>
    </describeLayout>
</se:Body></se:Envelope>
```

If user belongs to system admin or some other profiles, it is successful.

If user belongs to Standard Platform User, it's failed with response as:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:sf="urn:fault.partner.soap.sforce.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
        <faultcode> sf:INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS</faultcode>
        <faultstring> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id</faultstring>
        <detail>
            <sf:UnexpectedErrorFault xsi:type="sf:UnexpectedErrorFault">
                <sf:exceptionCode> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS</sf:exceptionCode>
                <sf:exceptionMessage> insufficient access rights on cross-reference id</sf:exceptionMessage>
            </sf:UnexpectedErrorFault>
        </detail>
    </soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

This issue occurs only one ORG. I have tried to test the same scenario in other ORG, but it does not occurs.
I suspect that I was setting something to make user does not have access right to the testing record type. But I didn't found anything in the profile settings and permission settings.

Please let me know the idea to prevent a user access to a record type. Thank a lot.